# Flexslider with content loaded using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, slider

I'm loading the content using:

`jQuery('slides').html(slides);`

I'm using this slider http://flexslider.woothemes.com/. Here is the question. How can I load this slider when the slides in the HTML structure will be added?

All works well when I enter to my website using direct link - then the content is loaded automatically. I have a problem when I load a "subpage" using jQuery, then slider doesn't work.

I tried to add:

```
 $('#carousel').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: false,
    animationLoop: false,
    slideshow: false,
    itemWidth: 210,
    itemMargin: 5,
    asNavFor: '#slider'
  });

  $('#slider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: false,
    animationLoop: false,
    slideshow: false,
    sync: "#carousel"
  });
```

after `jQuery('slides').html(slides);`, but it doesn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "subpage" further, and how this subpage is accessed?

Comment: `'slides'` isn't a tag name so that last part wouldn't work anyway

Comment: subpage - actual content is cleared using JavaScript and it's replaced with the new one (page title, description, slider etc.). There is added div structure of the slider.

Answer (score 0):

`'slides'` isn't a tag name so that last part wouldn't work. Try making that selector actually work, like by using `$('#slides')`

Comment: Unfortnately there is #slider block, not 'slides'.

Comment: I am not understanding your comment